# How to handle/cleanse invalid 0x14 in XML using Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm working on a C# client that downloads XML files from a web service via SOAP. For some of the older records hosted on the service, the XML comes across with, apparently, a 0x14 buried somewhere in it, which kicks an "Invalid whitespace character" exception. I'm using Linq to dump the XML into files. Is there some way to instruct Linq to dispose of invalid characters without losing the rest of the XML?

EDIT:

Here's the code I currently have for putting the XML to file:

```
 XDocument c =
            new XDocument(
                new XElement(nameSpace + "getCitationsResponse",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns1", nameSpace),
                    new XElement("list",
                        record.reportDateSpecified ? new XElement("reportDate", record.reportDate) : null,
                        new XElement("reportType", record.reportType),
                        new XElement("title", record.title),
                        new XElement("projectNumber", record.projectNumber),
                        new XElement("author", record.author),
                        new XElement("abstract", record.@abstract),
                        new XElement("numPages", record.numPages),
                        record.isDataTypeSpecified ? new XElement("isDataType", record.isRestrictedData) : null,
                        new XElement("comments", record.comments),
                        new XElement("attachments", from a in record.attachments
                                                    select new XElement("list",
                                                        new XElement("id", a.id),
                                                        new XElement("filePath", a.filePath),
                                                        new XElement("type", a.type)))));
```

I had to hack out some of it for the usual reasons, but what I removed is identical to the what's shown here.

I used SoapUI before I posted to see if I could figure out where the flaw was, but I don't *see* anything in SoapUI, and it doesn't generate an error itself.

EDIT #2:

Here's the exact error message and stack trace. Makes me wonder if I can actually do something about it or if I just need to work in something to log which records have invalid characters and try to pull 'em down manually with SoapUI.

```
Invalid white space character (0x14) in text to output
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Downloader.WebService.ApiService.getRecords(String username, String[] ids)
   at Downloader.Central.RecordLoop(ApiService svc, Int32 offset, String username)
```

getRecords is the API call generated by the wsdl, and RecordLoop is a recursive function I wrote to handle iterating through the API call to find updated records and push them to the Linq function I posted already.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for us, please?

Comment: You could look into this solution here: http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/

Comment: If it comes over with invalid bytes, then strictly speaking it is not actually XML... Just saying...

Comment: I added the Linq code and a little more explanation. I'll check out that link.

Comment: If the document comes across as a string, you could just `string.Replace` the bad characters. If it comes across as an XML document, you could potentially turn it into a string, do the `Replace` thing, and then re-create the document.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some of the comments above, it's possible to do execute different ninja tricks to get the SOAP response to comply with the XML specification.

If you choose to change the response to make it valid XML, you have to seriously consider if your changes are changing the meaning of the response.

As I see it, the problem is not on your side, but on the service side. If you can, you should try to get the service owner to upgrade the service to deliver proper formatted XML in their web services.

When dealing with 3rd party web services, I normally do the following:

- Enable full XML Schema validation on any requests and responses to and from 3rd web services. If the requests or responses aren't XML schema valid, then we (client and service) have a problem, which can be minor or major - but at least it's being attended to.
- Always log any schema validation errors, before trying to fix the content, to be sure that it's on record.
- Ensure that I'm fully aware of the system, business or legal implications on modifying the content.
- Ensure that I'm encoding the response using the proper encoding format - UTF8, Latin1 or others.

Invalid content is typically xml text elements, that contain illegal XML characters. The service side should either use XML encoding or base64 encoding, when transferring such text nodes, both to preserve formatting as well as content.

On the more technical part of actually changing the content so it become valid, I would normally add WCF behaviours, that would address the issues as doing so, kind of separate the concerns of fixing up the xml and the business purpose of service invocation.

It's also easy to remove the WCF behaviour, if or when the service gets updated to provide valid XML at any request.